# Displaying group of results from SQL

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I'm wondering if someone could help me out.

I'm trying to construct a SQL query.

I have a bunch of filenames, which i have put into an array like so

```
'filename1.jpg', 'filename2.jpg', 'filename3.jpg', 'filename4.jpg'
```

I also have a table with the following columns

```
date | filename | like | ipaddress
```

Everytime someone likes the filename a new row gets added to the table

What i need to do is count the likes for each filename and then print out the filename and like count for each of the files, im using classic ASP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT filename, sum(like) as likes FROM TABLE group by filename
```

to order by likes:

```
SELECT filename, sum(like) as likes FROM TABLE group by filename order by sum(like) desc
```

Comment: thanks for that ... Also, how would i then display based on the highest likes first?

Comment: Oh hang on a sec, that assumes that the filenames are by themselves, in the code i have them in an array